# Nested schema in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Thanks for your help and valuable time. As you suggested I have created the schema's as below. Now I want to get records based on customer name to calculate the hours spent by them on each category. Please help me out in this. Thanks in Advance.

/*var query = {'timesheets[0].categories[0].catname':"Admin"} // I want to get all the records or documents with category admin */

```
    Timesheet = new Schema({
      created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
      categories: [{
        catname: String,
        custname: String,
        hours: Number
      }]
    });

    User = new Schema({
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      email:String,
      password:String,   
      type:String,  
      timesheets: [Timesheet]
    });
    //timesheets: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Timesheet'}
    var User = mongoose.model("User",User);
    var Timesheet = mongoose.model("Timesheet",Timesheet);

    module.exports = function(app) {

        var timedata = {        
            created: new Date('2014-06-05'),
          categories:[{catname:"Admin",cusname:"Sony",hours:8}]           
      }

      var user = new User({
          name:"Nelson",
          email:"nelson@gmail.com",
          password:"welcome123",
          type:"Solutions"
          });

      var timesheet = new Timesheet(timedata);
            user.timesheets.push(timesheet);  

        user.save(function(err,user){ 
          console.log(user.timesheets.timesheet);     
        })
         //console.log('category name');
         //console.log(user.timesheets[0].categories[0].catname) 
        var query = {'timesheets[0].categories[0].catname':"Admin"}
        // I want to get 
         all the records or documents with category admin      

        User.find(query,function(err,catname){
            console.log('catname')
            console.log(catname)

        })
```

Comment: It is not the purpose of SO to have users edit their questions to become the answer, else how can it be of use to anyone?  Instead, please accept the answer you (obviously) found of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a child schema you should first define it and then insert into your primary schema. Alternatively, if you anticipate a lot of timesheets it's probably preferable to reference an independent schema. In both cases it would make sense to attach these to a User schema:

```
var Timesheet = new Schema({
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  categories: [{
    name: String,
    custname: String,
    hours: Number
  }]
});
```

**Using embedded documents:**

```
var User = new Schema({
  timesheets: [Timesheet]
});
```

Insert can then be done directly using:

```
// create new timesheet doc using your user doc
var timesheet = user.timesheets.create(myData);
user.timesheets.push(timesheet);
```

or simply:

```
user.timesheets.push(data);
```

**Using referenced documents:**

```
var User = new Schema({
  timesheets: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Timesheet'}]
});
```

insert with:

```
// push timesheet reference to your user doc
var timesheet = new Timesheet(data);
user.timesheets.push(timesheet._id);
```